# User with gold badge answers a question and immediately proceeds to close it as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, dupehammer

I have encountered (not often, thankfully) an instance of a user with a gold tag badge that answered a question, and then immediately proceeded to close it as a duplicate in a matter of seconds. It goes without saying that their answer wasn't deleted by them (as one would do when changing their mind).

Should I consider this an abuse of a privilege? And what should I, as a regular user on that Stack Exchange site, do about it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Should I consider this an abuse of a privilege?

It sure feels like it. Closing a question instantly after answering feels like using the system to prevent other answers (although my personal experience is that duplicate-closed questions don't attract that much votes any more). But of course, we can't be sure.

> And what should I, as a regular user on that Stack Exchange site, do about it?

Try to see if there is a pattern. Does it look like the user does it very often, then custom flag a post and explain your observations to the moderator. They will take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you're [referring to me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351124/253056), but I may have done this on occasion. It's not for any underhand motive such as you suggest above though. It's typically because it's a simple question and I've written a short knee-jerk answer, then realised it's probably a duplicate, gone searching for one or more duplicates and then closed the question. At that point, if the now-redundant answer seems reasonably correct and potentially useful I would tend to leave it in place, otherwise I would delete it. I don't see a problem with this, and it is certainly not some sort of pathetic attempt to gain rep and/or exclude other answerers (usually there wouldn't have even been any up-votes within such a short time window anyway).

Comment: I didn't have you in mind when posting this back in February. But my general understanding of SE is that if something is a dupe, we should close it as such and not answer. Leaving a short unfinished answer that doesn't address the post in particular or add anything beyond what's in the same dupes you linked, looks bad for a reason. Anyway, +1 for adding to the discussion here.